# Decomposing a Connected Graph into Walks

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem:** Assume G = (V,E) is a connected graph with 4 vertices of odd degree. Show G can be decomposed into 2 edge-disjoint simple (no edge is repeated) walks.

**Attempt at a Solution:** Suppose the four vertices of odd degree are A, B, C, and D.

- Find a path from A to B. Since no vertices are repeated, no edges are repeated.
- Delete the edges from that path. Now A and B have even degree.
- Now C and D are the only edges with odd degree; find a Euler walk from C to D. This uses up all the remaining edges, none of which are repeated.

I'm a little confused as to whether or not this is valid. Thanks for any comments/suggestions!

Comment: It seems like a natural enough approach, but you should perhaps be a bit more careful in places.  E.g. What if G is disconnected after the removal of the path from A to B?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's advice and hints! I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof is very close, but it is not valid yet.  As mentioned by Douglas Stones, you must find a way to make sure that your path does not disconnect the graph.

**Hint**: Make the $A,B$-trail maximal.  Why would this not disconnect the graph?

> Suppose maximal trail $P$ disconnects the graph.  Then, $C$ and $D$ must be in the same component by the handshake lemma.  Since the other component has all vertices with even degree, it must contain an Eulerian circuit $E$.  Moreover, it must contain at least one vertex $v$ in the trail $P$.  Then $A P v E v P B$ is a longer trail, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Did you intend your $C$ to be the Eulerian circuit in $APvCvPB$? A bit confusing since $C$ is already a vertex name.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for pointing this out.